# Save a file from gitlab-ci to a gitlab repository

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, gitlab-ci

I made this citlab-ci.yml file but i can find the html report in my repo at the end.

Can you tell me why ?

```
image: python

services:
- selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
variables:
  selenium_remote_url: "http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub"
cucumber:
  script: 
  - python --version
  - pwd
  - ls
  - pip install pytest
  - pip install pytest_bdd 
  - pip install selenium
  - pip install chromedriver
  - pip install pytest-html
  - cd test_pytest
  - ls
  - python -m pytest step_defs/test_web_steps.py --html=report.html
```

tx
Hadrien

Comment: I suspect that you should allow your runner to push the pytest report to your repo, see for example Laurens Stötzel answer on this gitlab's [feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/63858)

Comment: it's not my runner, it's the shared one.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually generate [test reports](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html) in gitlab. For this, generate an XML report from Pytest that would be stored in GitLab as an artifact. On your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
image: python:3.6

stages: 
    - test

testing:
  stage: test
  when: manual
  script:
    ...
    - pytest --junitxml=report.xml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
```

Then, you can download this report
[image]

or visualize it under the `Tests` tag of your pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct - the OP should beware though that once he `cd`'s into a directory, the path for his particular use case would need to be adapted to smth like `test_pytest/report.html`.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. I tryed both case an di always have this message :WARNING: report.xml: no matching files             
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: can you check if pytest generates a succesful message?, if this happens you should see a message like `Uploading artifacts for successful job`